# Transaction search always empty

Tags: c#, paypal, braintree

I try to search all transactions and i get always empty collection. in my paypal account i got alot transactions.

I tried any other requests and same i get empty from all requests

```
BraintreeGateway gw = new BraintreeGateway("access_token$...");
var request = new TransactionSearchRequest().Status.IncludedIn(TransactionStatus.ALL);
var collection = gw.Transaction.Search(request);

foreach (Braintree.Transaction transaction in collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(transaction.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `ALL` is not a valid transaction status, you are not receiving any results. The possible statuses are linked [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/search/dotnet#status). To search for all transactions, you would need to iterate over each transaction status. Here is an example:

```
request = new TransactionSearchRequest().
      Status.IncludedIn(TransactionStatus.AUTHORIZED,
                        TransactionStatus.SUBMITTED_FOR_SETTLEMENT
                        ...);  // add other statuses
collection = gateway.Transaction.Search(request);
```

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>